# Equivalent of string Array in C# from php and converting it into JSON

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, arrays, json

I have a piece of code that I've written in PHP like this:

```
$ids= array('12345','54321'); 
$post_data = array( 'token' => '******', 'goods_sn' => json_encode($ids) );
```

Before posting it to my server. I'm using .NET's restsharp library to achieve this. To replicate the PHP's array function i've created a string array in my application and then converted it into the JSON format like this:

```
string _token = loginToken;
string _goods_sn = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new string[] { "12345", "54321" });
var client = new RestClient("mysite.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
var post_data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { token= _token, goods_sn = _goods_sn });
request.AddBody(post_data);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
return client.Execute(request).Content;
```

But I keep getting reply that I have no token parameter in my request.. Am I doing something wrong here? Can someone help me out ?

Edit: guys so here is a format of data in PHP..

```
// example with goods_sn only element in JSON array

Array
(
    [token] => 4c4918
    [goods_sn] => "207833601"
)

//Example with multiple good_sn's ...
Array
(
    [token] => 4c4918
    [goods_sn] => ["207833601","118880101"]
)
```

And the output in C# with the following code:

```
string _token = loginToken;
 string[] _goodsSN = new string[] { "118880101", "207833601" };
 IDictionary<Object, Object> data = new Dictionary<Object, Object> {
 { "token", loginToken },
 { "goods_sn", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_goodsSN) }
 };

        var client = new RestClient("mysite.com");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        var post_data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(post_data);
```

is:

```
{\"token\":\"4c4918\",\"goods_sn\":\"[\\\"118880101\\\",\\\"207833601\\\"]\"}
```

This 2nd version is a little bit modified version of C# code I wrote in first example... I'm using a dictionary now...

Comment: Anyone guys? =)

Comment: Did you already compare the contents of the PHP-version of `$post_data` and the C#-version of `post_data`? Obviously the generated JSON seems to be different.

Comment: @khlr output in PHP 
Array
(
    [token] => 12345
    [goods_sn] => "207833601"
) 

looks like this is a dictionary in c# rather than a JSON , no ?

Comment: Yep, that's definitively a difference. So could you add the generated JSON-string of both versions so that we can compare them?

Comment: @khlr yes one moment I'll post right away =)

Comment: @khlr I've posted the output in both versions

Comment: Well, the generated JSON looks structurally identically...: PHP: `{"token":"******","goods_sn":"["12345","54321"]"}`, C#: `{"token":"4c4918","goods_sn":"["118880101","207833601"]"}`

Comment: @khlr maybe I'm doing something wrong with request code itself... Maybe missing some parameter to add, like url encoding or something ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138445/discussion-between-khlr-and-user987).